# Need to pass some values into an array in javascript but struggling

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to build an array with a collection of co-ordinates.. the example shows the array built like this..

```
stops = [{"Geometry":{"Latitude":51.507937,"Longitude":-0.076188}},
         {"Geometry":{"Latitude":51.51168,"Longitude":-0.114155}},
         {"Geometry":{"Latitude":51.5010063,"Longitude":-0.041407}}] ;
```

I am trying to build a loop that reads co-ords from elsewhere and pushes them in the stops array.. this is what i have so far but i know its wrong..

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("postcode");
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    postcode = x[i].innerText;
    lon = getLon(postcode);
    lat = getLat(postcode);

    myarray = [{"Latitude":lon,"Longitude":lat}];

    stops.push([{"Geometry":myarray}]);

}
```

Comment: *"but i know its wrong"* How do you know that? What's wrong?

Comment: because if I dump the array it looks completely different to the one i need in the first bit of code.

Comment: How does it look like?

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
myarray = [{"Latitude":lon,"Longitude":lat}];
stops.push([{"Geometry":myarray}]);
```

with

```
var myobject = {"Latitude":lon,"Longitude":lat};
stops.push({"Geometry":myobject});
```

Add also the missing `var` keyword in the `for` loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
```

When you don't, it makes the `i` variable global, which usually leads to painful bugs.